# Spring: Use application property inside an autowired constructor that instantiate a final field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've created the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below. The service should get a message and replace the vowels with a predefined `ugly.char` coming from `application.properties`.

**application.properties:**

```
ugly.char=x
```

**UglifyService.java:**

```
public interface UglifyService {
    String uglifyMessage(String message);
}
```

**UglifyServiceImpl.java:**

```
@Service
public class UglifyServiceImpl implements UglifyService {

    @Value("${ugly.char}")
    private char uglyCharFromAppProp;

    private final char uglyChar;

    @Autowired
    public UglifyServiceImpl() {
        this.uglyChar = uglyCharFromAppProp;
    }

    @Override
    public String uglifyMessage(String message) {
        return message.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", String.valueOf(uglyChar));
    }
}
```

**UglyCharController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class UglyCharController {

    private final UglifyService uglifyService;

    @Autowired
    public UglyCharController(UglifyService uglifyService) {
        this.uglifyService = uglifyService;
    }

    @Value("${ugly.char}")
    private char uglyChar;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "Usage: http://localhost:8080/some-message";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{message:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String uglifyMessage(@PathVariable String message) {
        String uglyMessage = uglifyService.uglifyMessage(message);
        return "The ugly char is: '"+ uglyChar +"'." +
                "<br>The uglifyed message is: "+ uglyMessage;
    }
}
```

**Application.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

The problem is that, instead of replacing the vowels, the service is just removing them.

When requesting `localhost:8080/mymessage` the response should be `mymxssxgx`, but I am getting `mymssg`.

**My questions are:**

1. Why the service is not working as expected?
2. What would be the right way to make it work, considering that I would like the `uglyChar` to be final inside the singleton service and to come from `application.properties`?

**Note:** The service starts to work if I replace `String.valueOf(uglyChar)` with `String.valueOf(uglyCharFromAppProp)`, but `uglyChar` would not be final, as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When object is instantiated, first the constructor is executed and then the values of the properties are set and `@Value` is executed. For this reason the value of uglyChar does not have the value of the property.

You can do it with:

```
   private final char uglyChar;

   @Autowired
   public UglifyServiceImpl(@Value("${ugly.char}") final char uglyCharFromAppProp){
       this.uglyChar = uglyCharFromAppProp;
   }
```